# Im trying to make an action t filter my files by day to different folders , any idea: doesnt work

Tags: mac, adobe-photoshop, automator

Please help, eed an action to select files like images, and videos basically to filter on different kind , and another action to filter by day.. cant make it worrk on automator, any advice ill appreciate.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and explain the exact problem you are facing  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question